# Automator Quick action to Move JPG that have RAW copy

Tags: bash, automator

i have a pictures in a folder with the similar names but different extension

```
2008.03.13__20.53.49__DSC_3020.NEF
2008.03.13__20.53.12__DSC_3018.jpg
2008.03.13__20.53.12__DSC_3018.NEF
```

I need to move .JPG files that have corresponding .NEF into a subfolder called "jpeg duplicate of NEF"
i have been using a such script on Windows

```
chcp 1252 >NUL
color A
if exist "jpeg duplicate of NEF"\ goto :move
if not exist "jpeg duplicate of NEF" mkdir "jpeg duplicate of NEF"
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Error create "jpeg duplicate of NEF"
goto :end
) else (
echo ......Directory created jpeg duplicate of NEF......
)
:move
for %%I in (*.jpg) do if exist %%~dI%%~pI%%~nI.NEF move "%%I" "%%~dI%%~pIjpeg duplicate of NEF\"
:end
echo ____________jpeg duplicate to folder, NEF leave in main folder____________
pause
```

But now i'm using MacBook and would like use similar script as a quick action. (i think it has to be bash script?)
Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
cd '/Volumes/Foto/_TMP move JPG test' || exit
mkdir -p 'jpeg duplicate of NEF'
for jpeg in *.jpg; do
    [[ -f ${jpeg%jpg}NEF ]] && mv "$jpeg" 'jpeg duplicate of NEF'
done
```

Comment: Now it's working, but how to use it without changing directory path every time? I mean it should use the current directory path.

Comment: It will use the current directory if you delete or comment out the first line (line starting with `cd`)

Comment: I'm sorry but it still using users home directory:(

Answer (score 0):

It shows an error, and creating a folder "jpeg duplicate of NEF" but inside users directory not inside the current directory (like this /Users/aleksandr/jpeg duplicate of NEF)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YMJw.png)

[image: Here is my setting of the Automator]

Comment: I'm trying to lunch it through the quick actions, right click on the TEST folder and run the script

Comment: It's a directory on a network disk /Volumes/Foto/_TMP move JPG test